# Entity Framework Update-Database with -ConnectionString

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Our web,config uses the same connection name for dev and production, with the only difference being the connection string itself.

I want to create Update-Database commands for dev and production that use a specified connection provided in the command.

I ran  `PM> get-help Update-Database -detailed` but did not see any relevant examples for what I am trying to do.

My question: What params need to be in the ConnectionString? Obviously I need initial catalog, data source, user id and password. Not sure about the others, though. Do I even need the connection name?

```
        update-database 
    -ConnectionStringName MyConn 
    -ConnectionString data source=10.10.10.20;
                      initial catalog=MyDatabase; 
                      persist security info=False;
                      user id=my_db_user;
                      password=1234;
                      max pool size=200;
                      MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
                      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The connection name is the same for both. Is there a way to do this with an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Bare minimum is:

- `DataSource` / `Server` / `Address` / `Addr` / `Network Address`
- `Initial Catalog` / `Database`
- `User Id` / `UID` + `Password` / `PWD` or `Integrated Security = true`

2) Default values will be used for other args not specified:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

3) `ConnectionStringName` is required only if you want connection string be taken from connection string defined in your web.config or app.config

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using web.config transformations instead?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In your Web.Release.config file you would have an entry like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbName" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.20; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; User Id=my_db_user; Password=1234;"
         xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Using `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"` means that you don't need to specify the provider again, only the connection string will change in your transformed web.config